# "Add unimplemented methods" in Xcode like in Eclipse

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, xcode, eclipse

I'm looking for a shortcut or any possibility to add unimplemented Methods like I use it everytime in Eclipse.

What I mean is if I declare a method in my .h file like:

```
#pragma mark Getter
-(NSDate *)date;
-(unsigned int)number;
-(double)longerNumber;
```

and after this declaration I can go into my implementation .m file import this interface and press some combination or get an advice where I can click on to implement these methods automatically.

Does somebody know something about that possibility or another fast workflow?

Thanks in advance
yves

Comment: good feature.. I believe it is not possible in xcode right now..Sad :(

Comment: I do something similar building snippets with shortcut, of course you can only use for repetitive methods in different projects

Answer (score 16):

I don't think it is possible in xcode. You can post an enhancement request [here](http://bugreport.apple.com/)..

You can just type "dash" then "space" and start typing the method name that you want to override. Now push Esc, you will get a list of all possible methods with that string you type. Atleast that reduce the pain of typing full method syntax.

[image]

[This](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=6180803#post6180803) macrumours thread might be a good read..