# Incomplete implementation warning

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way of having Xcode tell me what function is not implemented correctly that is triggering its "incomplete implementation" warning?

Comment: Did you try to google "xcode unimplemented function" before asking here ? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332689/add-unimplemented-methods-in-xcode-like-in-eclipse

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sometimes method names are not shown in the in-code warnings. In that case:

Go to the Issue navigator (the warning sign in the left pane), expand the warning, click on "Method declared here".

[image: Xcode issue navigator: Incomplete Implementation]

First, click the little arrow (1), then click one of the method names (2).

Comment: All it says is "Semantic Issue" then "Incomplete implementation". There is no actual reason listed

Comment: Ah, never noticed that little arrow

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the warning sign that Xcode displays at the very end of the file which is missing a method definition, you will see an additional message telling you which method it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes when you got this warning click on it .. for example it will take you the .m file .. in the warning there is a number for the methods in not implemented .. click on it and you will got the methods .. check the snap shots below.

[image]

[image]